# illegal under X or illegal in X?

Tags: grammar, idioms

> These subsidies are illegal under the WTO.
>
> These subsidies are illegal in the WTO.

The first sounds better, but I am not sure if it's correct since the WTO is an organization and now a law. Is there any situation where the "in" would be preferred to the "under"? And are both completely grammatical?

Comment: I would find it more natural to say _under WTO rules_.

Comment: Or " according the the WTO"